# Search and prove if some polynomials belong to an ideal

Tags: polynomials

I have the following pb :

Let consider ideal with the basis ${x, y, z}$. Check if next polynomials belong to it or not: $x^5yz^4 + y^3z^7 + z^9$ ;
$2x + 3y + z + 1$. Let consider ideal with the basis ${x + 2y + 3z, y + z, z}$. Check if next polynomials belong
to it or not: $x^5yz^4 + y^3z^7 + z^9 ; 2x + 3y + z + 14$.

But I don't know how to solve this.
I am looking for help to try to understand it.

Thank you in advance for your help,
Alexia

Answer (score 0):

It's a math question so you may consider to ask it in math.stackexchange, unless you want to ask how to do it using a computer algebra system such as Maple, Singular, etc. Or you want to write a code to do this. Which your post doesn't sound so.

Anyways, a polynomial in the three variables x, y and z, belongs to the ideal generated by the set {x, y, z}, if and only if it does not have a constant term, so `(x^5)*y*(z^4) + (y^3)*(z^7) + z^9` belongs to this ideal, but `2*x + 3*y + z + 1` does not.

Your second ideal is in fact the same ideal, note that `y = (y + z) - (z)`, and `x =  (x + 2*y + 3*z) - 2*( y ) - 3*( z )`. And so you can answer your ideal membership question of this case similar to the previous case.

Now in case you want to ask a computer algebra system to answer an ideal membership question. Here I write the command in Maple. You can use the command `IdealMembership` in `PolynomialIdeals` package, see its help page (https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=PolynomialIdeals%2FIdealContainment).

```
with( PolynomialIdeals ): # loading the package
J := PolynomialIdeal( x, y, z ): # defining an ideal
f := x^5*y*z^4 + y^3*z^7 + z^9: # defining a polynomial
IdealMembership( f, J ); # asking if f belongs to J
g := 2*x + 3*y + z + 1:
IdealMembership( g, J );
```

Here is a screenshot of what you will see in Maple by running the above lines.

[image]

There are many more computer algebra systems capable of answering the same question such as Singular or Mathematica. If you want to write a program yourself using a programming language or in computer algebra systems that have possibility of coding such as again Maple, you need to learn about Grobner bases. As a good elementary undergraduate book on this topic you can check the book "Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms" by Cox et al (https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-16721-3).